# Неправильные пути к файлам Laravel на хостинге

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, развертывание, deploy

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь 1 раз задеплоить свой проект, но столкнулся с нижеприведенной проблемой :

```
Warning: require(/var/www/u123456/data/www/тут домен/ANGELS-iT-DOCUMENTATOR/Application/public/../Application/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/u123456/data/www/тут домен/ANGELS-iT-DOCUMENTATOR/Application/public/index.php on line 17
```

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/u123456/data/www/тут домен/ANGELS-iT-DOCUMENTATOR/Application/public/../Application/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/u123456/data/www/тут домен/ANGELS-iT-DOCUMENTATOR/Application/public/index.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/u123456/data/www/тут домен/ANGELS-iT-DOCUMENTATOR/Application/public/index.php on line 17
```

Проект на хостинге reg.ru и находится по пути www/домен/ANGELS-iT-DOCUMENTATOR/Application/и тут все файлы проекта. Также есть ссылка на index.php из public, которая находится по пути www/домен.

Ниже код Index.php:

```
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../Application/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../Application/bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Буду очень рад любой помощи и подсказке, а если где-то ошибся, то поправьте меня )))

Comment: никакого `Application` в файле быть не должно) `__DIR__` уже содержит `www/домен/ANGELS-iT-DOCUMENTATOR/Application/` ваша папка **public** и **vendor**, **bootstrap** на одном ведь уровне) вообще тот файл не требует изменений обычно)

Comment: Я убрал только что Application из путей и действительно сайт немного начал работать, но теперь, на сайте не отображаются все bootstrap css и не работает роутинг на другие страницы

Comment: начните с азов) так как новый ответ вызовет новый вопрос... отвечать не имеет смысла) проще самому за 10 минут сделать, обратитесь к учителю или фрилансеру) как исправляется ошибка из вопроса надеюсь ясно из ответа выше).. да и.. в папке public вообще ничего трогать не нужно :) изучите концепцию ларавеля

Comment: Спасибо огромное за подсказки. В итоге я решил перейти на beget и сделал всё за 10 минут